# Where does `Read` come from in this OpenFST function?

Tags: c++, openfst

(Noob alert here---I'm not really a C++ programmer, just finding myself needing to reimplement some C++ code in Java.)

I am attempting to understand [the following function](http://www.openfst.org/doxygen/fst/html/util_8h_source.html#l00047) from OpenFST as part of an effort to enable reading of OpenFST binary files in JOpenFST:

```cpp
template <class T,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
inline std::istream &ReadType(std::istream &strm, T *t) {
        return t->Read(strm);
}
```

I can't determine what in this template declaration guarantees the existence of `Read` on `t`. I realize my understanding of `enable_if` and `is_class` are fuzzy, but I don't see what there could provide such a method.

Perhaps it comes from the broader context? Something that declares a `Read` for all class types??? Here are the imports in `util.h` where that function resides:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include <fst/compat.h>
#include <fst/types.h>
#include <fst/log.h>
#include <fstream>

#include <fst/flags.h>
#include <unordered_map>
```

Thank you for your patience with a confused Java dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't determine what in this template declaration guarantees the existence of `Read` on `t`.

Nothing guarantees the existence.

That is: If the template is instantiated with a `T` which doesn't have a `Read` member function, then the compiler will complain that a non-existent function was called.

From another perspective, the fact that the template is ill-formed unless `T::Read` exists (and is invocable with given argument) guarantees that `T` in any well formed instantiation of the template will have such member.

Comment: So the body of the function and not just the template and signature statically constrain the types that can be passed in? My only comparison with a language I'm familiar with is Rust's traits---there every method call in the body must be justified by the bounds placed on the types in the declaration.

Comment: @JoshHansen in a way, C++ doesn't have a direct way of constraining template arguments - although [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) rules make it possible to constrain the arguments indirectly (which is what `enable_if` does).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. So a template class is duck-typed in a way? But the checking is at comple-time, not runtime. My followup question then would be: how does `i32` (the type this function is being called on in the code I'm concerned with) end up having a `Read` function? Can intrinsic types be augmented with arbitrary methods somehow? Here is the calling code, btw: http://www.openfst.org/doxygen/fst/html/fst_8cc_source.html#l00062

Comment: @JoshHansen `std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type` prevents this template from being instantiated with non class types. Presumably there is an overload which would be resolved to in such case.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's there: 
`template <class T,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
inline std::istream &ReadType(std::istream &strm, T *t) {
    return strm.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(t), sizeof(T)); \
}`